# Pointer to function assignment, C

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

I don't understand why the following code generates a warning:

```
int func(double a, int b, char c)
{
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
    int(*myPointer)() = func;
    return 0;
}
```

I thought that in C, a function with an empty parameters list mean a function that can receive an unknown number of parameters. func4 happens to receive 3 parameters. So why is it incompatible with myPointer?

Its especially confusing because the following does compile without warning:

```
void boo()
{
     return;
}
int main()
{
    int(*pointerDude)(double) = boo;
    return 0;
}
```

What's going on?

Comment: No, function with empty arguments is a function receiving no arguments.

Comment: what warning are you getting?

Comment: [Example 1](http://www.ideone.com/w6Kks) and [Example 2](http://www.ideone.com/7dmxJ) both give the same warning on gcc-4.3.4. What is the compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the two cases is explained like this: if you pass a parameter to a function that accepts none, you are just consuming some memory on the stack. If you don't pass any parameter to a function that accepts a few, the latter is going to read random data from the stack.

***Update**: changed to community wiki to add these corrections from Pascal Cuoq:*

Casts of function pointer in both directions are legal, informative warnings from the compiler notwithstanding. Calling a function with the wrong prototype is illegal in both cases. Some ABIs mandate that the function clean up the stack, in which case passing parameters to functions that accept none corrupt the stack as surely as not passing parameters to functions that expect them.

C99 6.3.2.3 par. 8:

> A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a
>   function of another type and back again; the result shall compare
>   equal to the original pointer. If a converted pointer is used to call
>   a function whose type is not compatible with the pointed-to type, the
>   behavior is undefined

Comment: So in general it's legal for a pointer of type "pointer to function that receives parameters" to point at a function that doesn't receive parameters, but it's not legal for a pointer of type "pointer to function that doesn't receive parameters" to point at a function that does receive parameters?

Comment: Casts of function pointer in both directions are legal, informative warnings from the compiler notwithstanding. Calling a function with the wrong prototype is illegal in both cases. Some ABIs mandate that the function clean up the stack, in which case passing parameters to functions that accept none corrupt the stack as surely as not passing parameters to functions that expect them.

Comment: C99 6.3.2.3 par. 8: A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a function of another type and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer. If a converted pointer is used to call a function whose type is not compatible with the pointed-to type, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

This is the warning you get:

> warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type

You are passing `void` which means that will require a cast. You should use the right types.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC C compiler has certain assumptions which can cause very odd bugs because you're not telling it how much stack space it needs whenever that function is called. Especially since the definitions don't match this might allow someone to inadvertently read your function pointer declaration and assume no parameters and have the function return garbage. If you really want to take variable numbers of parameters use my_func(...) and varargs.

Answer (score 0):

A warning is just that, a warning. Honest.

In that case, the compiler *knows* you have an incorrect function pointer type and it blatantly tells you that. If you try to pass a number of parameters different then 3, then it will be issued an error.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is related to the casting of the parameters, because char is not 32 bits. Note that if you change the char to int this works fine. It is related to automatic promotion of variables.

Compare the two:

```
int func();
int func(double a, int b, int c) 
{
    return 0;
}
```

and

```
int func();
int func(double a, int b, char c) 
{
    return 0;
}
```

gcc gives you warning for the second, but not for the first

Comment: That's true...could you explain what you mean by automatic promotion of variables?

Comment: Having forward declarations like this is something that's worth avoiding in my opinion. They are confusing to maintain, especially if they are extracted into a header file.

Answer (score -1):

In C an empty parameter list means that the function does not take any parameters. I believe you are confusing an empty parameter list with varargs.

Changing your first example to include the parameters will remove the warning.

```
int func(double a, int b, char c)
{
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
    int(*myPointer)(double, int, char) = func;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "In C an empty parameter list means that the function does not take any parameters." No: http://david.tribble.com/text/cdiffs.htm#C99-empty-parm

Comment: What you said is true in C++, not C.